# Another mod_rewrite question

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've read the tutorials, I've read all the threads on this board and on tons of other boards, but I still don't get it.

User enters this into city search box: `Las Vegas, NV`

This is the query string it produces: `http://localhost/lcp3/carpetlist.php?city=las+vegas%2C+nv`

I want this: `http://localhost/lcp3/carpetlist/city/las-vegas-nv`

This is what I put in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/carpetlist/city/(.*)$ ./carpetlist.php?city=$1
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been working on this for days. It seems like it should be simple, but it's not :(

I know of a site that does what I want, but I'm not sure if you're allowed to post links.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you have it backwards try

```
RewriteRule ^/carpetlist.php?city=(.*)&?$ /carpetlist/city/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that rewrite rules in `.htaccess` files work with relative paths, where they work with absolute paths when used in server context. So try removing the first slash and see if it helps:

```
RewriteRule "^carpetlist/city/(.*)$" "carpetlist.php?city=$1"
```

Comment: In case of these trickynesses its always helpful to enable mod_rewrite's debug mode with `RewriteLog "/path/to/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3` to see what is actually going on.